# Parsing JSON Can't Acquire Name of Menu Item

Tags: javascript, json

So, I'm using AJAX to acquire a JSON file. I'm just trying to learn and understand how it works right now, but I'm planning on maybe using it in the future. So far, I'm actually able to acquire the file and parse it in JavaScript. What I'm unsure of is how to get the name of the menu item for the example I've created. Also, I've used [JSONLint.com](http://jsonlint.com) to check my JSON file, so I don't think it has something to do with that.
**JSON**

```
{
    "Sunday": {
        "name": "shrimp cocktail",
        "price": "8.99"
    },
    "Monday": {
        "name": "broasted chicken",
        "price": "5.40"
    },
    "Tuesday": {
        "name": "mexicano® tacos",
        "price": "2.99"
    },
    "Wednesday": {
        "name": "ruby's® champaign-cooked beef tacos",
        "price": "3.99"
    },
    "Thursday": {
        "name": "dc's green arrow super nachos",
        "price": "9.99"
    },
    "Friday": {
        "name": "jalapeno poppers",
        "price": "5.99"
    }
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
"use strict";

var xhttp, specialMenu, day;

function runWhenDone() {
    switch (new Date().getDay()) {
    case 0:
        day = "Sunday";
        break;
    case 1:
        day = "Monday";
        break;
    case 2:
        day = "Tuesday";
        break;
    case 3:
        day = "Wednesday";
        break;
    case 4:
        day = "Thursday";
        break;
    case 5:
        day = "Friday";
        break;
    case 6:
        day = "Saturday";
        break;
    }
    var c = document.createElement('p');
    c.innerHTML = "Special: " + specialMenu.day.name;
    document.body.appendChild(c);
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xhttp = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        specialMenu = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        runWhenDone();
    }
};
xhttp.open('GET', 'specials-menu.json', true);
xhttp.send();
```

**Code Snippet for Review**

```js
"use strict";

var specialMenu, day;

function runWhenDone() {
    switch (new Date().getDay()) {
    case 0:
        day = "Sunday";
        break;
    case 1:
        day = "Monday";
        break;
    case 2:
        day = "Tuesday";
        break;
    case 3:
        day = "Wednesday";
        break;
    case 4:
        day = "Thursday";
        break;
    case 5:
        day = "Friday";
        break;
    case 6:
        day = "Saturday";
        break;
    }
    var c = document.createElement('p');
    c.innerHTML = "Special: " + specialMenu.day.name;
    document.body.appendChild(c);
}
var specialMenu = JSON.parse('{"Sunday": {"name": "shrimp cocktail", "price": "8.99"}, "Monday": {"name": "broasted chicken", "price": "5.40"}, "Tuesday": {"name": "mexicano® tacos", "price": "2.99"}, "Wednesday": {"name": "ruby\'s® champaign-cooked beef tacos", "price": "3.99"}, "Thursday": { "name": "dc\'s green arrow super nachos", "price": "9.99"}, "Friday": {"name": "jalapeno poppers", "price": "5.99"}}');
runWhenDone();
```

I know it has something to do with `specialMenu.day.name`, yet I don't understand why it's not working. When designing, I've referenced this W3Schools tutorial for some help. [Click here.](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)

Comment: FWIW, it would be cleaner to pass the XHR response *to* `runWhenDone`, instead of using global/shared variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `specialMenu.day.name` with `specialMenu[day].name` :

```js
"use strict";

var specialMenu, day;

function runWhenDone() {
    day = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"][new Date().getDay()];
    var c = document.createElement('p');
    c.innerHTML = "Special: " + specialMenu[day].name;
    document.body.appendChild(c);
}
var specialMenu = JSON.parse('{"Sunday": {"name": "shrimp cocktail", "price": "8.99"}, "Monday": {"name": "broasted chicken", "price": "5.40"}, "Tuesday": {"name": "mexicano® tacos", "price": "2.99"}, "Wednesday": {"name": "ruby\'s® champaign-cooked beef tacos", "price": "3.99"}, "Thursday": { "name": "dc\'s green arrow super nachos", "price": "9.99"}, "Friday": {"name": "jalapeno poppers", "price": "5.99"}}');
runWhenDone();
```

In your code, you were looking for a property named "day", using the dot notation. To use a dynamic key (variable), use the bracket notation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
specialMenu.day.name;
```

do:

```
specialMenu[day].name;
```

.. since `day` is dynamic (a variable), not a literal.

Comment: `specialMenu[day]name;` does not work.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know: Needs the dot of course :)

Comment: No problem. Sorry, already gave answer to someone else. Thought I'd give you at least a +1, though.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above by *trincot* use `specialMenu[day].name` which should work.

 Also you should avoid global variables if possible.

```js
"use strict";

function runWhenDone(menu) {
    var day = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'][new Date().getDay()];
    var c = document.createElement('p');
    c.innerHTML = "Special: " + menu[day].name;
    document.body.appendChild(c);
}

var specialMenu = {"Sunday": {"name": "shrimp cocktail", "price": "8.99"}, "Monday": {"name": "broasted chicken", "price": "5.40"}, "Tuesday": {"name": "mexicano® tacos", "price": "2.99"}, "Wednesday": {"name": "ruby\'s® champaign-cooked beef tacos", "price": "3.99"}, "Thursday": { "name": "dc\'s green arrow super nachos", "price": "9.99"}, "Friday": {"name": "jalapeno poppers", "price": "5.99"}};
runWhenDone(specialMenu);
```